# How to identify all Archer applications/questionnaires that contains Custom Object

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

We are upgrading Archer to 6.8 and need to identify all applications/questionnaires that contain custom object so that we can check if these custom objects are still working in 6.8. Application (Questionnaire) custom object summary report can only check one application a time. Due to the number of applications/questionnaires, it is too time consuming to do it one by one. Looking for a SQL query to identify all applications/questionnaires that contain custom object. After that we can use the report to get details one by one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shawn, you can find the SQL query here to get what you're looking for, https://community.rsa.com/thread/206020#955448